# How to fix: image-rendering: pixelated Bugs

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, sass

I have done this page: https://loving-jepsen-c6f1de.netlify.com/
It draw pixel image on canvas by getting data from json file. I used i css property image-rendering:pixelated on canvas to make it work. But when I resize the window in chome developer tools the canvas is shaking and canvas is losting pixelating.Whats more It is losting pixelating when I resize the window by clicking "open in full window".

I used devtools to find whats wrong, its showing that canvas still has its image-rendering:pixelated (but its not working in fact).

JS for first picture (4x4):

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let btn_load_4x4 = document.getElementById('btn_load_4x4');
btn_load_4x4.addEventListener('click', fillCanvas4x4);

function fillCanvas4x4() {
  fetch(
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rolling-scopes-school/tasks/master/tasks/stage-2/codejam-canvas/data/4x4.json'
  )
    .then(function(resp) {
      return resp.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      canvas.width = 4;
      canvas.height = 4;
      let colors = data.map(el => el.map(el => '#' + el));
      for (let i = 0; i < canvas.width; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < canvas.height; j++) {
          ctx.fillStyle = colors[i][j];
          ctx.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
        }
      }
    });
}
```

CSS:

```css
.canvas {
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  padding: 20px;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

Comment: If someone will be interested I can give link on my Github repository, so you can watch the full code yourself.

Comment: I think you would need to redraw the canvas each time it is resized. Otherwise the pixelated image will no longer align perfectly with the devices pixels and you will see some antialiasing.

Comment: "each time it is resized" 
it is not resizing, it has fixed width & height. When the window is resizing the "bug" occurs. Or I misunderstood your answer?

Comment: I presumed you meant when you resize the window enough for the canvas to drop from 512px to 360px. Is this not what you meant? You have a media query in your CSS file that sets the width and height to 360px when the window is less than 580px wide.

Comment: thanck for your try to help? the problem was in my chrome version. Very dissapointed> I couldnt imagine that there is such a big differense between  78.0.3904.70 and little earlier versions